# Spring Cloud Gateway DataBufferUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

In spring-core, what is the purpose of joining LimitedDataBufferList in the Join method of the tool class DataBufferUtiles?

When the message body exceeds 256KB, an exception will occur.

How is the Bigger Message Body supported?